# Geeqie: keyboard shortcut for "up folder"

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, image-editor

I love Geeqie photo viewer, the best of all I've seen on Linux. However, I'm having problems setting the right keyboard shortcuts. The backspace key acts as "previous photo", but it would be way more intuitive for for it to act as "up folder" shortcut.

Where/how can I change that?

(couldn't find it in settings->keyboard)

Comment: One workaround I could imagine would be to create an "editor" to that function. It would "grep" the dirname from a random file that happens to be selected (that must be true, I guess, but unfortunately I think it's not always true, like once you just entered the folder or even without explicitly selecting a file), and give a remote command to geeqie to go to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an option for this either. I saw where you can disable the `Backspace` key here:

[image: keyboard prefs]

But saw no action for going up a directory. I also looked through the [Geeqie Project's website](http://geeqie.sourceforge.net/), in their [issue tracker](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/geeqie/report) & [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/geeqie/wiki) and amazingly no one else has asked for this feature either. I'd suggest filing a request to get this option added.

Additionally there's a configuration file for Geeqie here: `$HOME/.config/geeqie/geeqierc.xml`. But looking through this file I saw no method for changing up a directory their either.

Incidentally if you make changes to that file, and keep geeqie running, you need to run this command:

```
$ geeqie -r --config-load:HOME/.config/geeqie/geeqierc.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with Geeqie 1.4:

Once geeqie is running:

1. Go to Menu -> Edit -> Preferences -> Keyboard
2. Click on the Action header to sort entries by action name
3. Locate the entry for Up
4. Click on the Key (mid column) of the entry 'Up' and hit the desired key on the keyboard (e.g. `U`) to assign a new key/replace the previous one.
5. Apply